# What is the maximum storage size for TFVC in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

i know that there is a maximum project limit of 300 in Azure DevOps, but may i know what is the maximum storage size for the TFVC repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no size limit that I'm aware of. I've seen TFVC repos that are terabytes in size.

Comment: hi Daniel, thanks for your reply! May i know where you can check there is terabytes in TFVC?

Comment: In Azure DevOps, there's no way to check the total repo size for TFVC as far as I know. It shouldn't really matter. In on-prem TFS/Azure DevOps Server, there are tables you can check.